# Moving checkpoints around in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I have the following setup: I train a model on our GPU server, save a checkpoint using the tf.train.Saver() functionality within a tf.train.Supervisor(). After training, I want to transfer this model to my laptop and load it for inference purposes. 
When attempting to restore the model with `self.saver.restore(sess,self.checkpoint_path)`, (having re-created the proper graph beforehand), I get the following Error:

```
E tensorflow/core/client/tensor_c_api.cc:485] Cannot assign a device to node 'worker_0/save/Const': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/job:worker/task:0' because no devices matching that specification are registered in this process; available devices: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
Colocation Debug Info:
Colocation group had the following types and devices: 
Identity: CPU 
Const: CPU 
 [[Node: worker_0/save/Const = Const[dtype=DT_STRING, value=Tensor<type: string shape: [] values: model>, _device="/job:worker/task:0"]()]]
```

When analysing the properties of the cpkt object returned by

```
cpkt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(self.checkpoint_dir)
```

I see that `cpkt.model_checkpoint_path` points to the original path on the server, where the checkpoint was created, not to `self.checkpoint_path`, from which I tried to restore the model.

Are these two things connected? Or is there another reason for my above error message.

Any help would be appreciated,

Mat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your device assignments are saved, and the same devices are not available in your restore environment.

There's a flag `clear_devices` in `freeze_graph` and `import_meta_graph` which you can use to clear that information.

Alternatively, you can edit the `pbtxt` with your graph information and manually remove all lines starting with `device:`

Comment: Thx Yaroslav, updating the TF version, as well as understanding the saving & importing graph logic solved my problem!